# Relationship between Enthalpy and Gibbs energy

Tags: free-energy

I am a little stuck understanding the difference between Gibbs free energy and enthalpy. Both are measured in Joules and hence some sort of energy.

In a chemical reaction where C --> A + B

If A and B are more stable, this means energy will be released. This ΔPE is enthalpy(ΔH), correct? Enthalpy can be calculated from bond strengths after all.

In that case what does a reaction coordinate with Gibbs free energy tell us? ΔG is the change in free energy, but what is "free energy"?. Clearly that has to be different than the potential energy of the bonds since that is enthalpy (ΔH).

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please take a look at some existing questions and answers, for instance: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112815/change-in-gibbs-free-energy-vs-change-in-enthalpy?rq=1 Similar questions have been asked here many times before. If you still find these don't help post a new question or request that this question be reopened.

Comment: Also, in case you haven't please take the tour: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/what-is-the-difference-between-enthalpy-of-formation-and-gibbs-free-energy-of-fo?rq=1

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151090/entropy-changes-in-electrolytic-galvanic-cell